# javascript +function ($) { ... }(jQuery)

Tags: javascript

In bootstrap source code I found this function call:

```
+function ($) { ... } (jQuery)
```

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/button.js

What means "+" before function?

Comment: FYI, first result by Googling "plus before function javascript"

Comment: You are a lasy boy hum... Try to google it.

Comment: `+function()()` is the same as `(function()())`, Basically is saves you 1 less character.

Comment: sorry, I tried to search in Google by this queries: `javascript +function`, `javascript "+function"` and find nothing because "+" was ignored by google. I did not think to search "javascript plus function". This is my mistake